# xinitrc seems to not run some commands

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, dwm, startx, xinit

I am new to Arch and did a fresh install.
I have configured it to use dwm and I start it with startx. The problem is that some commands in xinitrc seem to not run. It clearly works to some extend, because dwm is starting, but i can't say the same for other commands.
My xintirc is located: ~/.xinitrc (or /home/xor/.xinitrc) and looks like this:

```
exec dwm
set xkbmap de
feh --bg-scale ~/background.png
xinput set-prop "UNIW0001:00 093A:0255 Touchpad" 349 1
xinput set-prop "UNIW0001:00 093A:0255 Touchpad" 326 1
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
```

It should start dwm(which it does), set the keyboard layout to german qwertz(which works), set a background image(which does not work) adjust some touchpad settings(which does not work), and do something with the nvidia driver(Not exactly sure what it does, i guess it enables the card/driver, but I know that the drivers work and I can use my GPU).
I can paste the not working commands in a terminal and they work.

Is there somewhere an error log for the file xinit, and what is the problem in my case?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your .xinitrc is that it just **starts** with exec.

This particular way to launch some command (here dwm) makes dwm replace the running shell, hence forbidding everything further down to be launched.
Quoted from man exec

> If exec is specified with command, it shall replace the shell
> with command without creating a new process.

I suggest you have a look to [Arch's Xinit wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xinit) in which you will notice that exec should be the last thing the .xinitrc script does.